# Clear error on Knockout-Validation

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-validation

I have a page setup with Knockout.js and using Knockout-Validation.

During the page load I put another plugin on a select box which fires a change, which fires the validation.  I need to be able to clear that error using JS so I can start with a fresh looking UI and give feedback on the form post or select box change.

I can't find anything that allows me to clear an error in Knockout-Validation.

Answer (score 31):

Probably a better way that follows what is already implemented in knockout validation is to say `property.isModified(false);`

if you have a whole view model to reset simply loop through all the validated properties and call that `isModified(false)`

See the [comment from Eric Barnard here](https://github.com/Knockout-Contrib/Knockout-Validation/issues/42)

Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks.  Also, this may be obvious to others but you have to do it after you clear the field. Example :  _thisComment(''); _this.Comment.isModified(false).  Easy validation reset.

Comment: this is exactly what `showAllMessages(false)` does internally, as answered by @yoann

Answer (score 25):

Late answer but if anyone needs it :

```
// assuming the ko.observable on the checkbox is called propBoolean
var propBooleanlValid = ko.validation.group(self.propBoolean, { deep: false });
propBooleanlValid .showAllMessages(false);
```

It will hide the message till the next validation.

Comment: This works great, thank you!  This should be in the ko validation docs.

Comment: note: make sure you have `messagesOnModified: true` in your configuration. if it's false then the message will show always

Comment: i feel this is the best of three

Answer (score 4):

Found the answer by implementing this Pull Request.

https://github.com/Knockout-Contrib/Knockout-Validation/pull/184

Gives me the feature I need.

Comment: Not to offend but I feel like this answer is not the one people should be taking as action when they want this functionality. whence my downvote. I upvoted your question though, its a good one! :)

Answer (score 1):

One way to solve it is by using a custom validator where you check for a flag in your viewmodel like "ignoreValidation". If that flag is true, then you let the validator pass.

Example of how that validator would look like:

```
viewmodel.userHasPremiumMembership.extend({
    validation: [
        {
            validator: function () {
                if (viewmodel.ignoreValidation) {
                    return true;
                }

                return viewmodel.userHasPremiumMembership();
            },
            message: 'User needs to have premium membership.'
        }
    ]
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use an entity manager make sure to not include the entityAspect in the validation since it is connected to all other entities. Also see
[How to rollback knockout validation errors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38345975/how-to-rollback-knockout-validation-errors)