# How to rollback knockout validation errors?

Tags: entity-framework, validation, knockout.js, rollback, knockout-validation

I use knockout validation 2.0.3 with entity framework 6.0 and get unexpected validation errors. Here is my workflow:

Step1: (works as expected) Create a new entity with an add-dialog and try to save the new entity. Validation errors are shown because some properties are missing. This is the wanted behavior. The user cancels the dialog and I call **unitofwork.rollback()** to undo the creation of the new entity.

Step2: Open the edit dialog for an existing entity of the same type. Try to save it as it is. => **The validation errors from step 1 are shown again!**

How can I clear the validation errors after step1?

If I only execute step2, the save action works just fine.

In a related stackoverflow question It was suggested to use

```
errors.showAllMessages(false);
```

That did not resolve my issue.

Related questions:

- [Clear error on Knockout-Validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13725401/clear-error-on-knockout-validation)
- [Clearing or resetting a knockout validation validatedObservable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17930588/clearing-or-resetting-a-knockout-validation-validatedobservable)
- [Knockout Validation - How to show error messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12098029/knockout-validation-how-to-show-error-messages)

Comment: There is *a lot* of code in the post, and quite a few bits of info about the server side of all this. It will make it easier for us to help if you trim things down to just the things needed to reproduce it (which would also require some view code to be *added*).

Comment: Its currently hard for me to provide a minified example and I thought the above code would at least be better than including no code at all. If I am able to confine the issue I'll update the question. I hope that someone already had a similar issue (combination of rollback and knockout validation) and is able to give some hint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the validation I used

```
validation.group(checkedEntity, { deep: true });
```

The full object tree also considers the **entityAspect** of the checked entity.
The entityAspect is connected to the **entity manager**. And that entity manager contains the old state of the entity.

The complete cycle is:

fooInstance => entityAspect => entityManager => entityGroupMap => Foo:... => _entities => **old entity instance**

Therefore I basically have two options:

- Do not use { deep: true }
- Make sure that after the rollback the entity manager does not contain the old entity any more:

> entityManager.rejectChanges();
>
> **entityManager.clear();**